# How to use MPI derived data type for 3D array?

Tags: c++, mpi

I want to write a parallel code that works on a 3D matrix where each processes has it's own sub matrix but for doing their jobs they need some information about their neighbouring processes' sub matrix (just boundary planes). I send these informations with point to point communication but I know that for large matrix it is not a good idea so I decide to use derived data type for communication. I have problem with `mpi_type_vector`: for example I have a `NX*NY*NZ` matrix and I want to send plane with constant `NY` to another process I write these lines for doing this:

```
MPI_Datatype sub;

MPI_Type_vector(NX, NZ, NY*NZ, MPI_DOUBLE, &sub);

MPI_Type_commit(&sub);
```

but it doesn't work (can not send my desired plane). What is wrong?
my test code is here:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{

    int const IE=100,JE=25,KE=100;
    int size,rank;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Datatype sub;
    MPI_Type_vector(KE,IE,IE+(JE-1)*IE,MPI_DOUBLE,&sub);
    MPI_Type_commit(&sub);

    if (rank==0){

        double*** a=new double**[IE];

        for(int i=0;i<IE;i++){
            a[i]=new double *[JE];
            for(int j=0;j<JE;j++){
                a[i][j]=new double [KE];
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<IE;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<JE;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<KE;k++){
                    a[i][j][k]=2;
                }}}

        for(int i=0;i<IE;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<JE;j++){
                a[i][j][0]=2;
            }}

        MPI_Send(&a[0][0][0],1,sub,1,52,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }

    if (rank==1){

        double*** b=new double**[IE];

        for(int i=0;i<IE;i++){
            b[i]=new double *[JE];
            for(int j=0;j<JE;j++){
                b[i][j]=new double [KE];
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<IE;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<JE;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<KE;k++){
                    b[i][j][k]=0;
                }}}

        MPI_Recv(&b[0][0][0][0],1,sub,0,52,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        for(int i=0;i<IE;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<JE;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<KE;k++){
                    if(b[i][j][k]>0){
                        cout<<"b["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]["<<k<<"]="<<b[i][j][k]<<endl;
                    }}}}

    }

    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a 3d matrix, in general you'd have to use a vector of vectors (because there are two strides involved) - which is possible, but much simpler is to use [MPI_Type_create_subarray()](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_create_subarray.html) which just lets you carve out the slab of a multidimensional array you want.

**Update**:  One problem in the above code is that the 3d array you allocate isn't contiguous; it's a collection of IE*JE allocated 1d arrays which may or may not be anywhere near each other.    So there's no reliable way of extracting a plane of data out of it.

You need to do something like this:

```
double ***alloc3d(int l, int m, int n) {
    double *data = new double [l*m*n];
    double ***array = new double **[l];
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        array[i] = new double *[m];
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            array[i][j] = &(data[(i*m+j)*n]);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Then the data is in one big cube, like you'd expect, with an array of pointers pointing into it.   This - the fact that C doesn't have real multidimensional arrays - comes up all the time with C + MPI.

Comment: ...I need more information than that.   What did you try, and how did you have a problem?

Comment: I test it:int a_size[3]={100,25,100};int subside[3]={100,1,100};int start[3]={0,0,0};int order=1; MPI_Type_create_subarray(3,aside,subside,start,order,MPI_DOUBLE,&sub);(I have a 100*25*100 matrix and just I want to send plane with constant NY from one process to another)above code sends other component of array,not my desired plane

Comment: How do you call the Send and Receive?  And order should be MPI_ORDER_C, not 1, although the two might be the same for some particular implmentation.

Comment: Looks good to me.  This should send the bottom-y plane from rank 1 to rank 0.  Does it not?  Oh, one last thing - how is the 3d array declared/allocated?  Is is contiguous?

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that; the data needs to be a contiguous block of memory, not a whole bunch of randomly allocated chunks.   I'll write the correct allocation code in the answer.

Comment: @JonathanDursi can you look at this Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040663/how-to-create-new-type-in-mpi

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  Jonathan Dursi. Here I want to publish complete code that creates a 3d matrix and uses derived datatypes for communication (only plane with constant y will be sent from one process to another).I used Jonathan Dursi's function posted above.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define IE 100
#define JE 50
#define KE 100

#define JE_loc 52
double ***alloc3d(int l, int m, int n) {
double *data = new double [l*m*n];
double ***array = new double **[l];
for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
    array[i] = new double *[m];
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
        array[i][j] = &(data[(i*m+j)*n]);
    }
}
return array;
}




int main(int argc ,char ** argv)
{
//////////////////////declartion/////////////////////////////
int const NFREQS=100,ia=7,ja=7,ka=7;
double const pi=3.14159;
int i,j,size,rank,k;
//MPI_Status status[10];
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Request request[10];
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Datatype sub;
MPI_Type_vector(KE,IE,IE+(JE-1)*IE,MPI_DOUBLE,&sub);
MPI_Type_commit(&sub);


double ***a=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
for (i=0; i<IE; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<JE; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<KE; k++) {
            a[i][j][k]=0.0;
        }
    }
}
if (rank==0) {
    for (i=0; i<IE; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<JE; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<KE; k++) {
                a[i][j][k]=2;
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Send(&a[0][0][0],1,sub,1,52,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}
if (rank==1) {
    MPI_Recv(&a[0][49][0],1,sub,0,52,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    for (i=0; i<IE; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<JE; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<KE; k++) {
                if (a[i][j][k]>0) {
                    cout<<"a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]["<<k<<"]="<<a[i][j][k]<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you that your reviewed code still isn't working correctly.
The reason why the output seems to be right is that IE and KE are equal. If you differ them you will see, that the values are written in alternating Y-indices.

If you have a look at the memory allocation of Jonathan Durst's code-sample which is like that:

```
[x0y0z0] [x0y0z1] [x0y1z0] [x0y1z1] [x1y0z0] [x1y0z1] [x1y1z0] [x1y1z1]   //or
{x0:(y0:[z0,z1]) ; (y1:[z0,z1])} ; {x1:(y0:[z0,z1]) ; (y1:[z0,z1])} //nx=ny=nz=2 
        <bl.len>  
 X             count                X  
     |<-          stride               ->|
```

you will see that you have a count of nx blocks with a blocklength of nz values and a stride between them of ny*nz.

Your code is working correctly if you change your data-type to:

```
MPI_Type_vector(IE,KE,KE*JE,MPI_DOUBLE,&sub);
```