# Send/Receiving 3D arrays in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I have a computational code that needs to be passed some arrays

```
int main()
{
    //...
    //..Allocating many 3D,1D arrays and initializing fixed-value arrays
    //..Initializing  named constants here at compile time         
    //..initializing other constants at run time (not changed during the program runtime)
    //...

    for(int n=0;n<=1000;n++){
        func1(); //Needs some 3D arrays to modify, some fixed-value arrays and lots of constants
        func2(); //Same here
        func3(); //Same here

    }

    //.. Data saving routines
    return 0;
}
```

I was considering splitting it up into an MPI program like so

```
//Allocate all of the arrays
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_Comm_World,&rank);

if(rank==0){
    //Initialize all of the arrays and named constants
    MPI_Bcast(); //Broadcasting all the constants and fixed-value arrays needed

    MPI_ISend();//Send 3D arrays needed by func1()
    MPI_ISend();//Send 3D arrays needed by func2()
    MPI_ISend();//Send 3D arrays needed by func3()

    MPI_IRecv();//Receive modified 3D arrays from func1()
    MPI_IRecv();//Receive modified 3D arrays from func2()
    MPI_IRecv();//Receive modified 3D arrays from func3()

    MPI_Wait(); //For all responses to come in
}
for(int n=0;n<=1000;n++){
    if(rank==1){
        MPI_Recv();//Receive broadcast of constants and fixed value arraysfrom master
        MPI_IRecv(); //Receive 3D arrays from master
        func1();     //Modify 3D arrays
        MPI_ISend(); //Send modified arrays back to master
    }
    else if(rank==2){
        //Similar code
    }
    else if(rank==3){
       //Similar code
    }
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

I have two questions:
1) I am passing around 300x300x300 3D arrays in addition to the initial broadcast of 30 constants
   and multiple fixed value 3D arrays that are initialized at run time. Will such a design as above 
   work ?

2) How do I go about passing 3D arrays using MPI_Datatypes ? C has no support for 3D arrays as a 
   first class language construct

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't see any problems here except you should correctly pass 3D arrays as you've mentioned in 2nd question.

2) [How to use MPI derived data type for 3D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736554/how-to-use-mpi-derived-data-type-for-3d-array)

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment on your proposed design, addressing part 1 of your question.

You should rethink the design of your program.  It is almost certainly not necessary, nor effective, to design a program which will run on 4 (and only 4) processes.  I suggest you consider:

- Use the facilities of MPI (specifically the routines `mpi_comm_size` and `mpi_comm_rank`) to have each process determine at run-time how many processes there are and what rank each process has.
- Use the number of processes and the rank of each process to decide the slice(s) of the array which each process gets.  If, for example, the program is executed on 30 processes then each process might get a `300*300*10` slice of the 3D arrays.
- It's entirely sensible, and often seen, for the master process in an MPI computation to read data from a file (or other source) and send it out to the other processes, and to reverse that pattern of communication when it comes to gathering and storing results.  But, it's also possible to have each process read its own data from the file system; if you have a parallel file system this may be faster, but even without that it can make it easier (if slower) for each process to take its turn reading from the file system.
- There is one out and out error in your outline.  You have only process 0 making a call to `mpi_bcast` and the other processes calling `mpi_recv` to match.  `mpi_bcast` is one of MPI's *collective* operations and must be called by all the processes which are to send/receive data.

As to your 2nd question, I think that Nikolay has pointed you in a useful direction.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is, I am a beginner and am not very confident about handing out slices of arrays based on number of processes. Is the basic design of running through the loop assigning different parts of the work to different processes sound ?