# MPI_Send complete structure from rank 0 to rank1 failing

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, openmpi

I am trying to send a structure containing number of variables from rank 0 to rank1 using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv. I am getting segmentation fault. Any help please?? Here is my code:

```
typedef struct {
double x;
double y;
double z;
int e[8];   
int ID;
int n_n[7];
int corner_ID;
int val;
int loc;
int proc;
int local;
int global;
int req; } MNODE;


MPI_Datatype send_node;
MPI_Datatype type1[13] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT,  MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
int blocklen1[13] = {1,1,1,8,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
MPI_Aint disp1[13] = {0,sizeof(double),2*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+8*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+9*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+16*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+17*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+18*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+19*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+20*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+21*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+22*sizeof(double),3*sizeof(double)+23*sizeof(double)};
MPI_Type_create_struct(13,blocklen1,disp1,type1,&send_node);
MPI_Type_commit(&send_node);

int NUMNP, i;
NUMNP = 20;

MNODE *node;
node = (MNODE*)malloc(NUMNP*sizeof(MNODE));

if (myrank == 0)
{
        MPI_Send(node, NUMNP, send_node, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

if (myrank == 1)
{
    MNODE *d_node;
   d_node = (MNODE*)malloc(NUMNP*sizeof(MNODE));

    MPI_Recv(d_node, NUMNP, send_node, 0, myrank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

Comment: Your displacements and therefore the MPI datatype size are wrong as you are using `sizeof(double)` everywhere. Use the `offsetof` macro (defined in `stddef.h`) instead.

Comment: Hi thanks, i'll try with offsetof. I wanted to know if the way i have done to send n recieve a struct is correct here??

Comment: I see. Then your question is a duplicate of [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040663/how-to-create-new-type-in-mpi).